# Finding Amount of Divisors

Tags: count, integer, scheme, racket, factors

I need to write a function in #lang racket that determines the amount of divisors a positive integer has. (Ex: 6 has 4 divisors; 1,2,3,6)

So far I have:

> (define (divides a b) (if (= 0 (modulo a b)) #t #f))

I need to use this helper function to write the function (divisors-upto n k) that that computes the number of divisors n has between 1 and k (so it computes the number of divisors of n
up to the value k).

Comment: Should be noted that the if is redundant. The body of the function just needs to be `(= 0 (modulo a b))`. Also, what's your question? Do you know how to use loops?

Comment: For my class I need to write a function in racket that determines how many divisors a number has. (6 has 4; 1, 2, 3, 4) (20 has 6: 1, 2, 4 , 5, 10, 20) ect. How do a make a function that can do this?

Comment: Yes, I got that. I mean what specifically are you asking here? Your questions too broad right now. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: And again, do you understand how to use loops?

Comment: I don't know how to write the (divisors-upto n k) function

Comment: I understand loops

Comment: Have you tried looping then? Try adding each number to a list in a loop only if `divides` is true for that number.

Comment: This could also be done using the `filter` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest done<sup>1</sup> with a `for` loop, in particular [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Ffold#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29), given that you already have your `divides` function.

```
(define (divisors num)
  (for/fold ([acc 0]
             [n (in-range num)])
    (if (divides n num) <acc+1> <acc>)))
```

Basically, you are looping over the list, and keeping an accumulator, and whenever a number is dividable, increment your accumulator. See if you can fill in the expressions for `<acc+1>` and `<acc>` in the code above.

<sub><sup>1</sup>You could also do this with list `length` and `filter`. See if you can figure out how.</sub>